# Apache http 2.2.17 installation error - libexpat.so.0 not found

Tags: apache, http

I am installing Apache 2.2.17 from source in Redhat 6.7 and seeing libexpat.so.0 not found. But I see the libexpat.so.0 available in /usr/lib64 and having /usr/lib64 path available in ld.so.conf file. 
After googling i found its a compatibility issue in the SO number libexpat.so.0 and libexpat.so.1. Reference:https://geekforum.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/install-apache-httpd-http-server/. I did removed the cache file following the above URL and ran ldconfig, but still seeing the error. I also did created the link libexpat.so.0 in /lib path to /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.0 but didn't work. 
Does anyone seen this issue in Redhat 6.7 and above. Is there any workaround for issues like this.
`[root@servername ~]# ldd /local/installs/2.2.17/bin/httpd
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00627000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00477000)
        libaprutil-1.so.0 => /local/installs/2.2.17/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x002ec000)
        **libexpat.so.0 => not found**
        libapr-1.so.0 => /local/installs/2.2.17/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00298000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00b61000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00182000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00a89000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x0032d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0086e000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00ce8000)
        **libexpat.so.0 => not found**
        libfreebl3.so => /lib/libfreebl3.so (0x0024e000)`

```
[edit] This issue is resolved.
```

Comment: Sounds stupid (and please forgive me, if it is ;)), but have you tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64` before trying to compile? This solved many similar problems for me.

Comment: ahuemmer@ exported the /usr/lib64 to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but seeing the same libexpat not found error.

Comment: OK, sorry to hear that, thought it was worth a try...

Comment: Ahuemmer @ do you know how the dependencies are handled in Linux. Since I have the libexpat.so.0 available and path is added then why is my binary not picking the dependency. Any clue to solve this.

Comment: No clue, sorry! If the path is correctly set and there are - if necessary - links to the libraries with correct names, I have never experienced any problems like this. :( But two more (dumb) thoughts:
- Are you perhaps trying to use a 32 bit Apache with 64 bit libs?
- Do your links have enough access rights?

Comment: Your thoughts are right, there is some issue with the 32 and 64 bit package. I did downloaded different version of Apache 2.2.17 and installed Apache and started it worked. In the ldd output, I see only one version of libexpat is been referenced. This seems to be come compatibility issue.  libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f28e2c7c000). I did not see second libexpat reference in the ldd output.

Comment: OK, great to hear that I could help. :) I will make up a "real" answer from these points for other's future reference. Feel free to vote on it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When library problems like this one occur, I usually check the following points to make sure, everything is like it should:

- Is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly set to include all the folders containing libs? This has to be the case at compile time already. You would do it like this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64:/other/dir/with/libs` ...
- If the libraries exist but don't have the name expected (which should not occur on "clean" systems / good applications), you can create a link like this: `ln -sf /path/to/existing/library.so /path/as/expected.so`. Mostly you will only have to fiddle with the file version endings (`.0`, `.1`, etc.) Please be sure to link to the correct library and version.
- Make sure, the libraries and these links have the correct access rights for the user trying to run the application depending on them

Also, check if you are accidentally mixing up 32 bit and 64 bit libs. As a rule of thumb, always use an application version matching your lib format and machine architecture (nowadays mostly 64bit). You cannot use a 32 bit application with 64 bit libs and vice versa. Also, using some libs as 32 bit and others as 64 bit won't work. Anyway, many 64 bit systems support running 32 bit applications by providing a second set of libs in 32 bit format ("[multilib](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Multilib)"), so you could try to run the 32 bit application if the 64 bit one fails or is not available.

Comment: From the beginning i see dependency issue due to architecture like 32/64 bit. After you first post, I did added the path /usr/lib64. But I missed to check the application architecture bit. The libexpat issue is fixed now and seeing mod_dav_svn.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64. I need to compile mod_dav_svn.so for Apache 2.2.17 32-bit version. I didn't downvote. If its me then by mistake. You are right that I have be careful with 32/64 bit applications. In my case 64 bit os, but apache 32 bit, mod_dav_svn is compiled using 64 bit. Do you know the Apache options to compile as 32-bit.

Comment: The option would be `CFLAGS=-m32` (should be exported at compile time). But rather than "downgrading" your apache to 32 bit, you should try to supply all libs necessary as 64bit versions. You can also try to `export LDFLAGS='-L$LD_LIBRARY_PATH'` after you set `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as described above.

Comment: Ahuemmer @ gcc is not taken by configure. configure: error: C compiler cannot create executable See `config.log' for more details. I didnt see anything related to fix gcc error.

Comment: I guess, that is because you don't have a 32 bit compiler installed. Is that possible? You could try to install one or enable "multilib" depending on your linux distribution.

Comment: Ahuemmer @ Earlier thought that I have to generate svn modules to server svn1.9 repos but coping the svn mod created using 1.6 seems to be working. I crossed the river now.. I Will post once everything is set and running.